# iOS: When to assign & when to create new copy of objects being assigned to a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, properties, automatic-ref-counting

(someone please edit the title, clearly I'm not great with lingo yet)

So, say I have an object called `DataRequester` whose job is to create an `NSURLConnection` and also be its delegate. I instantiate the object from my root view controller, and also provide a callback block (which is a property of `DataRequester`). When the `NSURLConnection` has finished loading, I call the callback and pass in the `NSData` as a parameter.

Now, inside my root view controller, where the completion block is defined, I want to store the `NSData` in a property `NSData (strong,nonatomic) *responseData` of the root view controller. My question is, in the callback should I be using

```
weakSelf.responseData = [NSData dataWithData:passedInData];
```

or can I simply use:

```
 weakSelf.responseData = passedInData;
```

(Where `RootViewController * __weak weakSelf = self)` Also the project uses ARC.

A brief explanation of the right answer would be appreciated and help me to understand how memory is managed (I've done a bunch of reading, but a practical example/explanation would go a long way for me).

Comment: I took a pass at clarifying the title, @JoshDG; what do you think?

Comment: Perfect. I appreciate that :) I think its an important question and something people probably struggle with without realizing. Hopefully now it can be found!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `copy` property:

```
NSData (copy,nonatomic) *responseData;  
// Then weakSelf.responseData = passedInData;
```

A `copy` property is suggested when the property is a pointer to a class that has also a mutable subclass, to avoid circumstances when your object mutates without that you know. Suppose for instance that there is another class that holds a pointer to this data object, and that it's mutable. It may be changed by the other class without that you know.

You don't need to copy it if the property is `readonly`, and you are sure that it points to an immutable object. However sending a copy message to an immutable object isn't expensive: it returns the object itself.